Conversion of url to pdf using chrome command line
I am using this code in powershell to convert url to pdf start chrome -ArgumentList "--headless --print-to-pdf=C:\Users\user\Desktop\file1.pdf link but it is not providing any css.
Is there any way I can download the proper lookalike of website to pdf,
I have also tried python's pdfkit, wkhtml2pdf, pyhtml2pdf (working well but some sites has anti bot protection which it cant bypass), but these are also not giving proper output.
How should I proceed further?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

PDF does not need any CSS provided. Do you mean that styling is excluded? This question lacks details extremely - no info what commands you used with mentioned tools, no info what's "not proper output".
